# breaking loop in c language

Tags: c

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    led_r1 = ~led_r1;
    led_r2 = ~led_r2;
    led_l1 = 0;
    led_l2 = 0;
    DelayMs(60);
    if (check == 1) {
       check = 0;
       right_check = 0;
       left_check = 0;
       goto new_pattern;
    }
    if (off == 2) {
       off = 1;
       right_check = 0;
       left_check = 0;
       goto reset;
    }
}
```

this is my code to blink two leds in my project...
It working fine but my program is correct...?
Is this way of using goto statement is correct..?
It will collapse the progr`enter code here`am..?`enter code here`

Is their any other way to terminate the program and jump to another part of program

Comment: Are you aware that C already has a `break` command? Why aren't you using it?

Comment: Goto statement is considered harmful. This was breaking news in 1968.

Comment: see in my program if(off==2) if it occur i have to another one location..?how can i do it without goto statement..sorry i'm new to c language.please suggestion me the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to answer your question based on the code you provided, since you haven't given any explanation of what happens at the `new_pattern:` or `reset:` labels, or how you are expecting the values of your variables to change inside a loop where there are no instructions that could cause this to happen.

However, as Lundin pointed out in the comments, you should try to [avoid the use of `goto` statements whenever possible](http://c-faq.com/style/stylewars.html). They tend to result in code that is unreadable and unmaintainable.

Instead, you should try to follow the principles of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). In particular, you should consider using functions to organize your code more logically. (Choosing suitably descriptive function names will also make your code easier to understand.)

A structured re-working of your code might look something like this:

```
#define NO_CHANGE      0
#define UPDATE_PATTERN 1
#define RESET_LEDS     2

int main() {
    /* ... */
    switch(flash_leds()) {
        case UPDATE_PATTERN:
            new_pattern();
            break;
        case RESET_LEDS:
            reset();
            break;
        default:
            /* Done flashing; no action required */
    }
    /* ... */
}

int flash_leds() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        /* ... */
        if (check == 1) return UPDATE_PATTERN;
        if (off == 2) return RESET_LEDS;
    }
    return NO_CHANGE;
}

void new_pattern() {
    /* update the pattern displayed by the LEDs */
}

void reset() {
    /* reset the LEDs */
}
```